# Uitextview scroll view position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I am trying to implement `UITextView` in my iphone app. `UITextView`'s content increases dyamically.

At same time I want to move scroll position also.

I am trying to `scrollToVisibleRect` method, but not getting any success.

Thanks

Comment: what do u mean by " i want to move scroll position also " ? u want to scroll to bottom of text ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question properly then you want to scroll your text view at the bottom of text.  To do so try this :

```
- (void) goToBottom
{
    NSUInteger length = self.myTextView.text.length;  
    self.myTextView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(length, 0);

    [myTextView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(length, 0) animated:YES];
}
```