# How to scroll to a certain point in UITextView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a huge amount of text, that I can't even scroll manually. So, I need to scroll my `UITextView` to a certain point.

I tested with following code that works, but the number of `(y)` is too big.

```
self.txtView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 100000);
```

So, is there any way to scroll to certain point in `UITextView`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712648/uitextview-scroll-view-position?answertab=active#tab-top this answer may help you achieve that

Answer (score 2):

`UITextView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView` class. So, you can scroll it to the show specific frame:

```
[textView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 20) animated:YES];
```

Also, you can scroll to a specific text:

```
[textView scrollRangeToVisible:[textView.text rangeOfString:@"Lorem ipsum"]];
```

Answer (score 1):

`UITextView` has a method:

```
setSelectedRange: (NSRange) range
```

If you know where in the string line 13 occurs, say location 237, then do:

```
[textView setSelectedRange: NSMakeRange(237,0)];
```

If you need to find out where line 13 occurs, you've more work ahead. I'd start by looking at sizeWithFont, remembering to nip about 16 points off the width of your textView so that iOS gets the sums right. (That said, if you have line breaks, then just find the location of the 13th (or nth) "\n".)

**Update:**

Following your further query in the comment:

There are lots of ways of finding the position of the nth \n. The following snippet isn't pretty, but it will do the job. You could also use rangeOfString and iterate through the "\n". In this snippet, if the target line is greater than the number of lines, it puts the cursor at the end. The code here assumes you have a UITextView property called userEntry.

```
int targetLine = 3; // change this as appropriate 0=first line

NSRange range;

NSString* exampleString = @"Hello there\nHow is it going?\nAre you looking for a new line?\nA new line in what?\nThat remains to be seen";

NSArray* separateLines = [exampleString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

if (targetLine < [separateLines count])
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<targetLine; i++)
    {
        count = count + [[separateLines objectAtIndex:i] length] + 1; // add 1 to compensate \n separator
    }

    range = NSMakeRange(count, 0);
}
else
{
    range = NSMakeRange([exampleString length], 0); // set to the very end if targetLine is > number of lines
}

[[self userEntry] setText: exampleString];
[[self userEntry] setSelectedRange:range];
[[self userEntry] becomeFirstResponder];
```